# Is "if ( somefunction( ) )" blocking in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
test = function(x){   
    if ( some conditions ) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}


if (test(y)) {document.write("You have done this before!")​}​;​

console.log("Checked!");
```

The intention is to check if the user performed some action in the past. These are just mock up codes that do not really reflect what I am actually doing though.

**Question:**

I am relatively new to node.js so please forgive me if this sounds trivial. Suppose test(y) is true. Can I be sure that the console.log will be executed after the document.write? Even if test(y) takes a long time to run?

In other words, I need "if (test(y))..." to be blocking. I understand that passing a function as an argument, e.g. setInterval(test(y),100); can be async and non-blocking. But what about "if(test(y))..."?

Comment: Depends on what test(y) does internally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NodeJS has both synchronous (blocking) and asynchronous (non-blocking) functions. *(More accurately: The functions* themselves *are always "blocking" but a whole class of them start something that will complete later and then return immediately, not waiting for the thing  to finish. Those are what I mean by "non-blocking.")*

The default in most cases is asynchronous (and they accept a callback they call when the thing they've started is done); the synchronous ones tend to have names ending in `Sync`.

So for example, [`exists`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) is asynchronous (non-blocking), it doesn't have a return value and instead calls a callback when it's done. [`existsSync`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) is synchronous (blocking); it *returns* its result rather than having a callback.

If `test` is your own function, and it only calls synchronous functions, then it's synchronous:

```
function test(x) { // Obviously a nonsense example, as it just replicates `existsSync`
    if (existsSync(x)) {
        // The file exists
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// This works
if (test("foo.txt")) {
    // ...
}
```

If it calls an asynchronous function, it's asynchronous, and so it can't return a result via a return value that can be tested by `if`:

```
// WRONG, always returns `undefined`
function test(x) {
    var retVal;

    exists(x, function(flag) {
        retVal = flag;
    });

    return retVal;
}
```

Instead, you have to provide a callback:

```
function test(x, callback) {

    exists(x, function(flag) {
        callback(flag);
    });
}

// This works
test("foo.txt", function(flag) {
    if (flag) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation! ^__^

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this code is synchronous executed and "blocking". But console.log will be executed every time the script runs because you only omitting the document.write in the if statement.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, console.log will be executed every time. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

The blocking/non-blocking terminology is a bit confusing here, I would say **'all functions in Node.JS are blocking and all IO in node standard library is non-blocking, except when indicated explicitly by Sync suffix in function name'.**

Comment: Isn't setInterval(function(),5000) non-blocking? Even if "function()" isn't IO and takes a long time to complete? (newbie question)

Comment: Timers are IO in that sense (and handled by the same syscalls and underlying descriptors). setInterval blocking in the sense that you can be sure than no other code is executed until setInterval finished, and only side effect is that timer referencing function() is created. function() itself is called later (again, in a blocking way) from event loop.